# Chrome Developer tool not reflecting saved changes to my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I am debugging my code using chrome developer tools(CDT), and I noticed an error with one of the classes I declared. I wrote

original input:

```js
class Person = {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

so CDT gave me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` 
Cool.. I opened my file in atom and fixed the error, and saved my file.

New input:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I reopened CDT to reinspect my js file but the CDT `sources` still shows the original input and the `console` still displays error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

I have tried inspecting my file on firefox and I get the same error. I have closed my js file and reopened it. atom shows that my changes(new input) was saved, but for some reason chrome and firefox only sees the previous version of my file. Please advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Browser cache may be a problem , just clear the cache and try.. It might be one reason...

Comment: I tried a `Hard reload` and a `Empty cache and hard reload` none seemed to work, so I just switched OS so the issue is resolved for now... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear history and try again !!!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I forgot to add in my question that I tried a  `Hard reload` and a `Empty cache and hard reload`. Since my PC has to OS, I switched from Ubuntu to windows and that seemed to resolve the issue.